# Test iOS app on device without apple developer program

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to run the app on an iPhone. I developed the app in xcode 5.0.
Is it any way to install the app on the phone, which is not physically connected to my computer (i.e. via email)?

Please suggest.

Comment: No you can't you need to have a developer licence then create some provisioning profiles and some certificates so you can develop on a real device. Also why are you telling us your girlfriends birthday is next month? If you like sharing personal information so much please can you give me your bank details?

Comment: Please visit : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download XCode 7. Apple has changed its policy regarding permissions required to build and run apps on devices. Until now, Apple required users to pay $99/year to become a member of Apple’s Developer Program in order to run code on physical iPhone and iPads. As part of the new Developer Program, this is no longer required. Apps can be tested on devices, no purchase necessary.

Comment: Download XCode 7 and export the build for AdHoc distribution, as @slxl stated before

Answer (score 0):

This is very true from Xcode 7 onwards. The membership fee is not required for testing but for submitting your app to the App Store, you'll have to pay $99/year to Apple.